# Does Hbase have a replication policy of its own or is it inherited from HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

Since `HBase` is built on top of `HDFS` which has a replication policy for fault tolerance, does this mean `HBase` is inherently fault tolerant and data stored in `HBase` will always be accessible thanks to the underlying `HDFS`? Or does `HBase` implement a replication policy of its own (e.g table replication over regions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create replica of regions in Hbase, as mentioned [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/137951/how-to-enable-region-replication-on-region-server.html). However, note that HBase high availability is for read only. It is not highly available for writes. If region server goes down, then until regions are assigned to a new region server, you will not be able to write.

To enable read replicas, you need to enable Async WAL replication by setting `hbase.region.replica.replication.enabled` to true. You will also need to enable high availability for the table at creation time by specifying REGION_REPLICATION value greater than 1, as in [docs](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_creating_a_table_with_region_replication):

```
CREATE 't1', 'f1', {REGION_REPLICATION => 2}
```

More details can be found [here](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_hadoop-ha/content/ch_HA-HBase.html).

Answer (score 2):

The concept of replication in `HBase` is different than `HDFS` replication. Both are different in different context. `HDFS` is the file system and replicates data for fault tolerant and high availability features from the data file. While `HBase` replication is mainly around fault tolerant, high availability and data integrity from a database system perspective.

Of course, `HDFS` replication capability is used for file level replication for `HBase`. Along with it, `HBase` also maintains copies of its meta data into backup nodes (which are again replicated by default by `HDFS`).

`HBase` also have backup processes to monitor and recover from failure. like Primary and Secondary Region servers. But the data loss in the region server is protected by `HDFS` replication only.

Hence, the `Hbase` replication is mainly around recovery of failure and maintaining data integrity as a database engine. It is just like any other robust database system like `Oracle`.